# Deploy flutter app onto the google play as a production

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to deploy are beta-testing app to google play as a production mode. We are able to deploy as a beta testing last week, and after that I added lot's of change to our code. Finally I finished writing code for the app now, and thinking to deploy the app as production on google play. I was wondering, if I should update the Android App Bundle on Beta section in app releases then hit "release to production" button (on Beta section page in app releases), or I should go to Production track and drop the new Android App Bundle. Does it really matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matters, tho, if you create a new appbundle and deploy it in production mode, you should after that disable your beta bundle, otherwise users that have access to beta will see two apps in the Play Store.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know how I can disable the bundle??

Comment: So I'm trying to run flutter build appbundle in the same project. But does it mean creating a new appbundle or updating??

Comment: @Yuya by making the `flutter build appbundle` command in the same project, you're just creating a new appbundle that contain you project in his actual state. So at every update of your project, you should create an appbundle and publish it to the Play Store though the production mode if you want to make this build public.